# Unmatched parenthesis: missing ')' in #if directive

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I wrote this simple program

```
#include <time.h>
int main()
{   
#if ((clock_t)1000)
    int x = 10;
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

On compilation, I see the following error:

> Error C1012   unmatched parenthesis: missing ')'

Why am I getting this error?

Changing the line from:

`#if ((clock_t)1000)`

to:

```
#if (clock_t)1000
```

resolves the compilation error.

But I can't do that, since ((clock_t)1000) is defined as a macro using the #define directive in the limits.h header file as :

```
#define CLOCKS_PER_SEC  ((clock_t)1000)
```

and I need to use that directly.

---

EDIT:

Please pardon me for framing the question in such an unclear way. 
Reframing my question now:

I have the following code:

```
#include <time.h>
#define DUMMY_CLOCKS_PER_SEC ((clock_t)1000)
int main()
{   
#if CLOCKS_PER_SEC != DUMMY_CLOCKS_PER_SEC
    #error "out of sync"
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

But this gives the compilation error:

> Error C1012   unmatched parenthesis: missing ')'

Comment: The preprocessor uses its own simple language which is unrelated to C++. You can't use C++ symbols or type-names (like `clock_t`) as part of preprocessor expressions. And you certainly can't do C++ expressions, including casting, with the preprocessor.

Comment: can you tell us what `#if ((clock_t)1000)` is supposed to do?

Comment: note that the preprocessor can only make compile-time determinations. it is used to define symbols, control what gets compiled, and for text-replacement

Comment: ((clock_t)1000) is not defined by me. Its already define in the limits.h header file as:
#define CLOCKS_PER_SEC  ((clock_t)1000)
I am using it to compare it with my own defined DUMMY_CLOCKS_PER_SEC. If both matches than I proceed, otherwise an error is raised

Comment: And what is your goal with that weird `#if ((clock_t)1000)` construct?

Comment: I think you need to find a few tutorials on the preprocess and how it works. `#define CLOCKS_PER_SEC ((clock_t)1000)` defines a macro named `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` which when used will be expanded to `((clock_t)1000)`. If you want to check if `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` exists (which it must do in standard C++) then you use `#ifdef CLOCKS_PER_SEC`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I am not checking whether this exists or not. I am comparing it with my own defined variable DUMMY_CLOCKS_PER_SEC.
In VS2013, this worked fine, because at that time CLOCKS_PER_SEC was defined as 
# define CLOCKS_PER_SEC 1000.
Now, I am porting the code to VS2017, and the definition of CLOCKS_PER_SEC has changed to :
#define CLOCKS_PER_SEC  ((clock_t)1000) 
which causes the error.

Comment: @VarunKalra How does your code compare anything?

Comment: `static_assert(CLOCKS_PER_SEC == DUMMY_CLOCKS_PER_SEC)`. Also, don't define your own.

Comment: @Barmar I use the following code to compare CLOCKS_PER_SEC and DUMMY_CLOCKS_PER_SEC : #if CLOCKS_PER_SEC != DUMMY_CLOCKS_PER_SEC

Comment: This is why it's so important to have a [Minimal, ***Complete***, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)! Before you post your next question, read that link. Also [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @VarunKalra Why doesn't it say that in the code in the question?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I will read that for sure and my apologies for framing the question in an unclear way. I have updated the question with the correct problem.

Comment: @Barmar  My apologies for framing the question in an unclear way. I have updated the question with the correct problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The preprocessor doesn't know anything about C++ datatypes, and doesn't understand cast expressions. It's used for simple text processing, and `==` and `!=` can only compare single tokens.

Do the comparison in C++, not the preprocessor.

```
static_assert(CLOCKS_PER_SEC == DUMMY_CLOCKS_PER_SEC, "out of sync");
int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

Don't worry about the runtime performance overhead. Since both macros expand to literals, the compiler will optimize it away.

Comment: I can' t do this, since instead of return 10, I need to define the #error macro.

Comment: Then I think you're out of luck. `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` is not intended to be used in preprocessor expressions, it's meant for C/C++. See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.0.4/cpp/If.html#If for what's allowed in a preprocessor `#if` expression.

Comment: Not out of luck at all. You can simply use `static_assert(CLOCKS_PER_SEC == DUMMY_CLOCKS_PER_SEC, "Your error message here");` instead of `#if` and `#error`.

Comment: @VarunKalra see my comment above, but by the way, if your program is designed to only work when DUMMY_CLOCKS_PER_SEC is identical to CLOCKS_PER_SEC, why don't you just use CLOCKS_PER_SEC instead?

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou Thanks, I've updated the answer to use this with his error message.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou I'm guessing he has some other code that's dependent on a particular clock frequency, and it can't use the C++ header file (maybe it's not C++, or it's running on a different OS). So he needs to keep the two things in sync, and `DUMMY_CLOCKS_PER_SEC` represents what's in the other s/w.

Comment: @Barmar Another solution to this problem is to use const expressions which is a feature of c++11.

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing a preprocessor macro definition ([`CLOCKS_PER_SEC`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/CLOCKS_PER_SEC)) with its expansion (that is *implementation defined*, and in your case seems to be `((clock_t)1000)`).

It's not very clear what you want to do in your code.

If you want to check if this macro is defined, you can use the preprocessor `#ifdef`, e.g.:

```
#ifdef CLOCKS_PER_SEC
  // your code
#endif
```

Anyway, this [`CLOCKS_PER_SEC` macro](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/CLOCKS_PER_SEC) is defined by the standard, so it should be always defined in a standard-compliant `time.h` library implementation.

If you have something different in your mind, please clarify your goal.

**EDIT** Based on your clarifying comment below, you may want to use an `if` to compare the values (expansions) of these two macros:

```
if (DUMMY_CLOCKS_PER_SEC != CLOCKS_PER_SEC) {
  ...
} else {
  ...
}
```

Comment: I have defined my own DUMMY_CLOCKS_PER_SEC as 
#define DUMMY_CLOCKS_PER_SEC ((clock_t)1000) and I need to compare the 2 macros CLOCKS_PER_SEC and DUMMY_CLOCKS_PER_SEC using #if CLOCKS_PER_SEC != JP_CLOCKS_PER_SEC. But, doing this comparison generates the compilation error defined in the question, which I am trying to solve.

Comment: @VarunKalra: OK, so it sounds like you need to use a simple `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

> ((clock_t)1000) is defined as a macro using the #define directive in the limits.h header file as :
>
> ```
> #define CLOCKS_PER_SEC  ((clock_t)1000)
> ```

The file does not define a macro named `((clock_t)1000)`. It defines a macro named `CLOCKS_PER_SEC`. `((clock_t)1000)` is the value of the macro.

`((clock_t)1000)` is not a macro and is something that cannot be used in an `#if` directive.

Comment: My appologies for using the wrong terminology. I have updated the question with the correct terms.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for all the responses everyone.

Another solution I figured out for this problem is to use constexpr specifier which is a feature of c++11. ConstExpr allows us to evaluate the value of a variable or a function at compile time.

Changing the code from:

```
#if CLOCKS_PER_SEC != DUMMY_CLOCKS_PER_SEC
    #error "out of sync"
#endif
```

to the following resolves the issue:

```
constexpr int DUMMY_CLOCK_NOT_EQUAL = (DUMMY_CLOCKS_PER_SEC != CLOCKS_PER_SEC) ? 1 : 0;
#if DUMMY_CLOCK_NOT_EQUAL
#error "out of sync" 
#endif
```